# Need advise on converting existing data-layer\db to Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

Converting our existing data-layer to the Entity Framework has been on my to-do list for a long time. I've started to really look into it and it seems like a daunting task. Our current setup uses typed datasets, data adapters, and a few hundred stored procs.  So my question is for anyone who has done something similar how did you proceed?  Do I convert all the stored procedures to lamaba expressions to try to integrate them into the Entity Framework? Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritting hundred stored procedures into linq-to-entities queries is not a good idea. If you move to EF you should still use those stored procedure and only simplify their calling and mapping results into entities or complex types which will replace your data tables.

Datasets offers disconnected change set pattern so there can be a big difference in using data sets and EF entities. Based on the way how you use datasets you will probably have to check Self tracking entities in Entity framework 4 which also offers disconnected change set pattern but has some other disadvantages.

This can be quite difficult and challenging task so I personally don't think that it is good idea without any previous experience with EF.